# owl carousel: how can I change direction of changing pictures?

Tags: jquery

how can I change direction of changing pictures? 
I want to make pictures move diagonally. I can't find information about that anywhrer

Answer (score 0):

Slide Elements in Different Directions

With the built-in slide methods, elements are shown by sliding them down and into view. But what if we want to slide something from the bottom up and into view? The trick here is to use some judicious CSS. Let's start with a simple HTML structure:

HTML

```
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
  <button>slide it</button>
  <div class="inner">Slide from bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slide {
  position: relative;
}
.slide .inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slidebottom button').click(function() {
$(this).next().slideToggle();
});
});
```

Read the tutorial [here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/) ...